# On the ring structure of $K_0$ of the punctured spectrum of a regular local ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, algebraic-k-theory, algebraic-vector-bundles

Let $(R, \mathcal m, k)$ be a regular local ring of dimension at least $3$. Let $K_0(X)$ be the Grothendieck group of algebraic vector bundles over the punctured spectrum $X =Spec R \setminus \{\mathfrak m \}$ . Now $K_0(X)$ also has a commutative ring structure induced from the tensor product of vector bundles.

My question is : Is $K_0(X)$ an integral domain as a ring ?

Comment: $K_0(X)=\mathbb{Z}$ in your case.

Comment: @Mohan: that does not seem right ... vector bundles on the punctured spectrum are not trivial I think ...

Comment: No, they are not, but if the ring is regular local, they just give the rank in the $K$-group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an expansion of my comment above. Giving a vector bundle on $X$ gives you a finitely generated module $M$ over $R$ such that its restriction to $X$ is your vector bundle. But, since $R$ is regular, you have a finite free resolution of $M$ over $R$ and thus restricting to $X$, you have a finite free resolution of your vector bundle. Thus, in the $K$ group, your vector bundle is just the alternate sum of finitely many trivial bundles and the rest should be clear.